# Caching Bitmap Images

Tags: android, caching, xamarin

I am working with #Xamarin.Android# Application. I don't know how to cache  Bitmap images. In Xamarin.Android Application how to cache data?

Comment: How and why do you want to cache images? If you are loading images via a url, Xamarin will automatically cache them. If it's a byte[] you just store it in memory, or in a file or even in SQLite (depending upon size). PCL's don't have a caching providing but if you want that to cache byte[] in memory let me know and I can point you to that code.

Comment: Yes,Please provide the code.Actually I have created horizontal RecyclerView and when I scroll RecyclerView forward it downlods that images but even when i scroll it back it also downloads that images again..and when i once deploy my application in my device it works fine when internet is on but as i turn off my internet ,error pops up with webexception. @Adam

Comment: Use Picasso library. It loads from local or remote uri, it caches automatically, and it has very intuitive syntax. Also, I've used with RecyclerView and it works well: http://square.github.io/picasso/

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to recommend you look at this library

https://github.com/LukeForder/Xamarin-Bindings-Android-Universal-Image-Loader

It is a Xamarin Binding for this Android Library

https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

And it does everything you want in regards to caching images.

As for caching a byte[] in memory you can create PCL and use this code
http://ranahossain.blogspot.co.uk/2014/01/cache-provider-for-portable-class.html

Answer (score 0):

I recently had to write something to do this, and wasn't able to use the libraries mentioned by Adam because we needed to do some custom post processing of the images before they were cached etc.

I can't share the code I wrote, but I referred to [this article](http://www.mobtowers.com/xamarin-android-image-caching/) *heavily*. In my case, we also had to load the images remotely before processing, so the prior article on that same site [here](http://www.mobtowers.com/xamarin-android-using-remote-images-in-lists/) was a lot a lot of help.